# Missing View Columns that cause nulls to be saved when using Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Just need some clarification.

If I have a form with fields that should not be modified by the user then I need to use the HiddenFor helper to pass those values through otherwise those values will be missing and Model Binding will ensure Nulls are stored for those Field Values.

Of course this seems over zealous of the Model Binder, and one would think that if a field did not exist at all in the View(response stream) then that field would be left untouched. Obviously an EditFor field with a value of "" is different and that value should be null or "".

The only other approach I have come across is to use objects mappers such as Automapper to ensure nulls are ignored.

At the moment I will just use hidden fields to pass the values through.

Thoughts on the above appreciated or rather what is the recommended method for dealing with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: The model state isn't preserved anywhere on the server so without a `HiddenFor` there is no way it can tell what the original value of the field should be. Of course if the fields should not be modified by the user they shouldn't be model bound either (even with hidden fields) as the user would still be able to post arbitrary values back.

Comment: Thanks for this. So what would the recommended approach be to deal with "non user modifiable" fields if even they should not be model bound> Thanks.